# What logs should I check after a break-in?

Tags: linux, log-files, forensic-analysis

I've asked this same question on `superuser` but I didn't have that much succes. I'd like to learn more about forensic analysis, and I'm doing the challenges from [Project Honeynet](http://www.honeynet.org/). I need to check the logfiles and see the IP's that connected remote to a computer. I have a `dd` image of the harddrive, and the only service that was running was `apache`. Besides Apache's logs, what other logfiles should I look into, to see who connected to the computer? I'm only interested in remote connections. As for the Linux system, we can consider it generic, with a 2.4 kernel.

Comment: Related but side note-you can't trust anything on a system that is broken into. It should be logging everything to a remote system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything. auth, syslog, messages, .bash_history, last, utmp, wtmp, cron logs, /tmp. thats just a start really because an attacker with root privs can alter anything (and probably did), so you have to find a place that was forgotten.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [neoice](https://serverfault.com/questions/84375/what-logs-should-i-check-after-a-break-in/84420#84420) and Bart.

Also, maybe check if any file-alteration monitoring tool (or rootkit monitoring tool) was installed (examples include, but aren't limited to: samhain, tripwire, rthunter). samhain/tripwire *could* give you the list of modified files, and rootkit hunter *could* show you not only suspected rootkits, but also other problematic areas. Actually, you may even want to run your rootkit hunter in a chroot to that disk image...